# Unable to update Item quantity in cart module in Yii

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii, cart

I am implementing cart module in Yii, I am able to save everything in session array but each time same product is added the quantity get increment but again got set to 1.

here is my function code snippet

```
public function actionAddToCart($id) {
$found = 0;
$cart = array();
$cart_item = $this->loadModel($id)->name;
$cart_price = $this->loadModel($id)->price;

$newItem = Yii::app()->session['cart'];

foreach ($newItem as $item) {
    if($id == $item['id']) {
        echo "quantity" . $item['quantity'];
        $item['quantity'] += 1;
        $found = 1;
        $newItem[$id] = array('name'=>$cart_item,'price'=>$cart_price, 'quantity'=>$item['quantity'], 'id'=>$id ) ;
        echo "Element Found=" . $found . 'Now quantity is '.$item['quantity'];
    }

}
if($found != 1) {
    $newItem[$id] = array('name'=>$cart_item,'price'=>$cart_price, 'quantity'=>1, 'id'=>$id ) ;
    Yii::app()->session['cart'] = $newItem ;
    echo "New added" ;
}
//array_push($cart, Yii::app()->session['cart'][$id] ) ;         //array('name'=>$cart_item,'price'=>$cart_price)) ;

echo json_encode(array("items"=>$newItem));
Yii::app()->end();

}
```

Seeking help thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using any extension for implementing cart functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the **SESSION CART** where there is found ,
Also Your code it just a bit mess( in the sense of optamization).

try this.

```
 public function actionAddToCart($id) {

        $newItem = Yii::app()->session['cart'];

        if(isset($newItem[$id])){
            $newItem[$id]['quantity']++;
            echo "Element Found= 1 Now quantity is ".$newItem[$id]['quantity'];
        }
        else{
            $cartItem= $this->loadModel($id)
            $newItem[$id] = array('name'=>$cartItem->name,'price'=>$cartItem->price, 'quantity'=>1, 'id'=>$id ) ;            
        }

        Yii::app()->session['cart'] = $newItem ;
        //array_push($cart, Yii::app()->session['cart'][$id] ) ;   
        //array('name'=>$cart_item,'price'=>$cart_price)) ;

        echo json_encode(array("items"=>$newItem));
        Yii::app()->end();

    }
```

Comment: Yeah I got it few minutes before. Thanks this made my code correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the global variable `$found`.

Here is the modified code:

```
    public function actionAddToCart($id) {
        $found = 0;
        $cart = array();
        $cart_item = $this->loadModel($id)->name;
        $cart_price = $this->loadModel($id)->price;

        $newItem = Yii::app()->session['cart'];

        foreach ($newItem as $item) {
            if($id == $item['id']) {
                echo "quantity" . $item['quantity'];
                $item['quantity'] += 1;
                $GLOBALS['found'] = 1;
                $newItem[$id] = array('name'=>$cart_item,'price'=>$cart_price, 'quantity'=>$item['quantity'], 'id'=>$id ) ;
                echo "Element Found=" . $found . 'Now quantity is '.$item['quantity'];
            }

        }
        if($found == 0) {
            $newItem[$id] = array('name'=>$cart_item,'price'=>$cart_price, 'quantity'=>1, 'id'=>$id ) ;
            Yii::app()->session['cart'] = $newItem ;
            echo "New added" ;
        }
        //array_push($cart, Yii::app()->session['cart'][$id] ) ;         //array('name'=>$cart_item,'price'=>$cart_price)) ;

        echo json_encode(array("items"=>$newItem));
        Yii::app()->end();

        }
```

Comment: Well as you can see i am printing **new added** so if that id is not present its clearly say **new added**. I guess found is not the reason for hurting the code. 

More over the found is declared in function blocks so its scope is throughout the function with the update value.

Every time same item is added the quantity is 2 it didn't go to 3 or 4 no matter how many times i repeat it.

Comment: well! it has nothing to with GLOBAL, as $found is still in scope.